# How to detect that directive B is inside directive A

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So on the page I have 3 angular custom directives AA BB and CC.
Sometimes BB is inside AA

```
<AA>
  <BB></BB>
</AA>
```

Some other time BB is inside CC

```
<CC>
  <BB></BB>
</CC>
```

Think of it like
1) I'm displaying BB inside a preview viewer
2) I'm displaying the BB on some kind of dashboard
I would like to detect inside the controller of BB if BB is inside directive AA or CC.
I can check the path in the url ($location) - but maybe there is another way ?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know this?  How does it affect what you're trying to accomplish?  If you're trying to access the parent directive, you can use require with an array where you'd set both AA and CC to optional.  I'm just trying to figure out how to best give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, to expand on my comment, if you use [require](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) in your directive you can pass in an array of directives names and if these are set to optional, it won't throw an error if the required directive is not found.  Instead, it will simply return undefined in the controllers array.  Setting required controllers as optional is done by preceding the name of the directive with a `?`.  The caret `^` tells it to locate the required controller by searching the element and its parents.  Since 1.3, you can even use `^^` to attempt locate the required controller by searching the element's parents only (so with this one you can't have both directives on the same element).

Therefore, you can do this:

```
app.directive('BB', function() {
return {
  require: ['?^AA','?CC'],
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
     parent = controllers[0] ? 'AA' : 'CC';
     alert(parent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi nice I think the optional require could work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If its your own directives, you can attach a property on the scope. From the child directive, and if its not isolate scope, you can traverse up the scope chain and determine if that property exists.

Alternatively, you walk the DOM upwards to the body element, and check for the directive element.

Examples will soon follow...

Answer (score 0):

Use `require` key in the return value of your directive declaration.

```
require: '^myTabs',
```

Here is example from AngularJS website:

```
app.directive('myPane', function() {
return {
  require: '^myTabs'
 }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KR9bgWesS8pl8Qq06aJq?p=preview

There is also an article explaining about this directive communication.

https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/directive-to-directive-communication